# Is there a way to implement Google OAuth in React Native Expo without ejecting?

Tags: firebase, react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, expo

Is there a way to setup the Google OAuth in Expo without ejecting it? I've looked at [expo-google-sign-in](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/), [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin), and [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), they require ejecting Expo. I like the Expo's features and I'd like to keep the development within in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my RN project I found npm packages to do the jobs that otherwise required me to eject expo. The link below may be worth a shot for your case.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client